# In SharePoint 2007 what feature or solution added the WebPart Page Doc library templates?

Tags: feature, sharepoint-enterprise, document-template, web-part-pages

In SharePoint 2007 what feature or solution added the WebPart Page Doc library template?

We have it on one Farm, but not another.  Is it part of the Fab 40? A site feature or a Site collection feature?